# using strip function for the condition in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
add = ' '
while add != '0'.strip(): #IMPORTANT: whatever the user inputs is always converted to a string!!
    add = input("What else do you need to buy? If you are done, enter 0. ")
    shopping_list.append(add)
```

When running this code, I will try to input

```
  0
```

so basically 0 with some spaces. but then the

```
What else do you need to buy? If you are done, enter 0.
```

runs again. I know I can just add

```
add = add.strip()
```

to solve this, but then it will add 0 to the list. so I tried doing this

```
add = ' '
while add != '0': #IMPORTANT: whatever the user inputs is always converted to a string!!
    add = input("What else do you need to buy? If you are done, enter 0. ")
    if add != '0':
        shopping_list.append(add)
    else:
        add = add.strip()

#print('Here is your shopping list: \n' + str(shopping_list))
print('Here is your shopping list: ')
for item in shopping_list:
    print(item)
```

but yea that causes it to not recognize 0 if i put a few spaces in it. Anyway to solve this?

Here is my full code:

```
#Shopping list

print("Welcome! Let me track what you need to buy.")
first_name = input("What is your first name? ")
last_name = input ("Great! What is you last name? ")
full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
print("Alright! So your full name is " + full_name.title() + ".")

#shift + tab to get rid of indent from multiple lines
shopping_list = []
print("Now, lets get onto creating your shopping list!")
_1 = input("What is the first item that you need to buy? ")
shopping_list.append(_1)

add = ' '
while add != '0': #IMPORTANT: whatever the user inputs is always converted to a string!!
    add = input("What else do you need to buy? If you are done, enter 0. ")
    if add != '0':
        shopping_list.append(add)
    elif add == '0':
        add = add.strip()

#print('Here is your shopping list: \n' + str(shopping_list))
print('Here is your shopping list: ')
for item in shopping_list:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `strip` method on the wrong string. You want to strip the whitespace from `add`, then compare that result to `0`:

```
while True:
    add = input("...").strip()
    if add == '0':
        break
    shoping_list.append(add)
```

Comment: thank you so much! I almost forgot that .strip() removes space on the left and right of an item, not the space inbetween which I was concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
while True:
    add = input("What else do you need to buy? If you are done, enter 0. ")
    if add.strip() == '0':
        break
    shopping_list.append(add)
```